# JQuery UI , draggable card not working after drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a problem when I dragged a card in card lists, the card I dragged and dropped in the new card list is not available to drag again.

My JQuery code is

```
$("#card-list").droppable({
    accept: ".card",
    drop: function( event, ui ){          
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        $(this).append(dropped.clone().removeAttr('style'));
        dropped.remove();
        }
    });

   $(".card").draggable({
      revert: true,
      opacity: .5
    }),
```

and my HTML is

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="card">
      Some text
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      Some text
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      Some text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6" id="card-list">
    <div class="card">
      Some text
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      Some text
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      Some text
    </div>
  </div>
</div
```

see
[live example](https://codepen.io/yousefmohamed/pen/MWvrMBN)

---

another problem
I want to make the draggable card at the top of the new list, not at the bottom

 or 
when added at the bottom body scroll down to the added card.

Comment: Problem is that when you clone a dragged element, it will not have been initialized by $(".card").draggable. So you have to run that again for the new element

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As was mentioned, after drop and clone, the card is not longer initialized as Draggable. You can initialize it to address the issue. You may also think about Sortable versus Droppable.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen , thanks but how can i do this by "code"

Comment: @Twisty sortable is powerful but i don't need to sort elements Just drag and drop them.